# Application with Chrome-Style Tabs using EasyTabs in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a C# Application with Chrome-Style Tabs using EasyTabs in WinForms, but I am getting the following error code:

The designer must create an instance of type 'EasyTabs.TitleBarTabs' but it cannot because the type is declared as abstract.

I have followed the Youtube-tutorial beneath as a guideline.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVFjegJK8EY

Code:

```
using System;
using EasyTabs;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class AppContainer : TitleBarTabs
    {
        public AppContainer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AeroPeekEnabled = true;
            TabRenderer = new ChromeTabRenderer(this);
        }

        public override TitleBarTab CreateTab()
        {
            return new TitleBarTab(this)
            {
                Content = Form1
                {
                    Text = "New Tab"
                }
            };
        }

        private void AppContainer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend posting the code you wrote instead of posting the video link on YouTube. Highlight the error you're getting in your code and it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am new to this site and forgot to post my code with it.

Comment: Did you implement ALL the abstract methods/properties from the base class? That's what the error hints at.

Comment: According to [this article](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/574/creating-a-csharp-application-with-chrome-style-tabs-using-easytabs-in-winforms), it's normal that you can't see the designer.

"Note that if you try to see the AppContainer Form in the Visual Studio designer, you will see this:  

You will get this error, because as explained, the designer is trying to draw something that is abstract (our form is abstract once extends the TitleBarTabs instead of Form), therefore an exception will be thrown only if you try to see the Form in the designer, otherwise is totally valid."

Comment: As I understood from that, you have no problem. As long as you're following the tutorial correctly, everything will run as intended. I suggest launching your application to make sure of this, otherwise this seems not to be an error, it's normal.

Comment: I understand that I am not able to see the designer, but when I'm trying to run the program it says it can't because of multiple errors

Comment: Well, that's something else to look at. I just followed the exact same article I posted in my previous comment and it worked perfectly. If you have some other error that you can't seem to fix, I guess they merit another question.

Comment: The only errors I'm getting are the one from the code above in the class:

Comment: confirming @PaulKaram, the linked article just works

Comment: Thank you guys, I forget to put a new before Form1. I didn't see it in the video, but in the picture it was clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal to see this error when you try to view AppContainer.cs directly.

> The designer must create an instance of type 'EasyTabs.TitleBarTabs' but it cannot because the type is declared as abstract. 
>   Let that not deter you from achieving what you wanted to achieve. Ignore the error and simply right click on AppContainer.cs and select **View Code**

```
using EasyTabs;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class AppContainer : TitleBarTabs
    {
        public AppTabs()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AeroPeekEnabled = true;
            TabRenderer = new ChromeTabRenderer(this);
            Icon = mBible.Properties.Resources.appico;
        }

        public override TitleBarTab CreateTab()
        {
            return new TitleBarTab(this)
            {
                Content = new Form1
                {
                    Text = "New Tab"
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

That should be enough to generate new tabs for you.

Now to create tabs easily lets assume you have a form 'MainForm' and the tab you want to be generating is 'Form1' here is what we do

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using EasyTabs;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public static AppContainer tabbedApp = new AppContainer();

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tabbedApp.Tabs.Add(new TitleBarTab(tabbedApp)
            {
                Content = new Form1
                {
                    Text = "New Tab"
                }
            });
            tabbedApp.SelectedTabIndex = 0;

            TitleBarTabsApplicationContext applicationContext = new TitleBarTabsApplicationContext();
            applicationContext.Start(tabbedApp);

            this.Hide();
        }

    }
}
```

You can always add to your tabs a new tab easily by calling this code on another form

```
    AppContainer.tabbedApp.Tabs.Add(new TitleBarTab(AppContainer.tabbedApp)
    {
         Content = new Form2 { Text = "Another Tab" }
   });
   AppContainer.tabbedApp.SelectedTabIndex = 0;
```

I hope that helps and anyone looking for help on similar issues.