# how to create a new tab with different forms? (Using EasyTabs)

Tags: c#

I already used this tutorial but it didn't work for me

[Application with Chrome-Style Tabs using EasyTabs in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54572837/application-with-chrome-style-tabs-using-easytabs-in-winforms)

when I try to create a tab with another Form in cases if it calls "Settings" it doesn't work.

the error generated that simply nothing happens.

**context**
Tabui, is the AppContainer the base you use to redeem the forms.

```
  public void settingstab()
    {
        var AppContainer = new Tabui();


        AppContainer.Tabs.Add(new TitleBarTab(AppContainer)
        {
            Content = new Settings { Text = "Another Tab" }
        });
        AppContainer.SelectedTabIndex = 0;


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: Not familiar with the product, but it seems like calling `new Tabui()` and then adding the settings tab to that new object, rather than an existing Tabui object, is likely a mistake.

Comment: that's not it, I've tried it and it doesn't work